# Which keypoint detector is used by ARToolkit(version 5)?

Tags: artoolkit, keypoint

In their blog post , they have mentioned that they use FREAK descriptor but they haven't mentioned which detector are they using to identify the keypoints . Does anybody know anything about it???

Answer (score 0):

The version 5 of the ARToolkit works using SURF features.

ARToolkit 6, to be released soon, will use FREAK features, based on Harris corners.

Regards,

Daniel

Comment: Hi Daniel , according to http://artoolkit.org/blog/2016/05/freak-image-features  , ARToolkit is already using FREAK descriptors as it was published on May'16 . I want to know what keypoint detectors are they using as they have not mentioned it there?

Comment: As mentioned already, the FREAK features used in ARToolkit 6 which are generated from Harris Corners. The article is talking about ARToolkit 6. The main intention of the article was to discuss features, with the knowledge of the FREAK features being released soon.

Comment: Go to Github and the ARToolkit 5 page. Search the repository for the word FREAK, you will find there are no results. Then search the word SURF and you will find references in the code. I hope that's enough evidence for you.

Comment: Hey man ! Surprisingly , there is an entire folder on FreakMatcher in Artoolkit5 git repo . Check it out https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit5/tree/master/lib/SRC/KPM/FreakMatcher
Looks like your answer is wrong . Still you may check and correct it and update your answer .

Comment: @Kartik. The answer is still correct. ARToolkit5 uses SURF features. If you get the FREAK features in KPM working, please be sure to commit these changes back to ARToolkit5. ARToolkit6 works exclusively with FREAK features bases on Harris corners. Clearly, the "comment' that is incorrect as FREAK was searched for and not Freak. (Note the casing). We look forward to you committing the working version of artoolkit5 with Freak features back to the main repository.

Comment: @WebSight hey! I haven't yet undergone through the code of ART5 , it was just a cursory glance and I was responding to Dan Bell's comment about there being nothing in search of "Freak" .  So , I don't know how the ART works at present , so it would not be appropriate for me to comment on it . However , if you know better , you can correct my knowledge for sure. Also whats this about "FREAK" vs "Freak" ? Please elaborate and also how do you guys keep talking about ART6 when it hasn't released ? Also tell me what the files in "FreakMatcher" folder does? U seem to know something about it!!!

Comment: @Kartik. 1) FREAK is an acronym so it is appropriate to capitalise it (Fast Retina Keypoints). 2) We develop for ARToolkit so we are working with the code whilst it is under development. 3) After further investigation, appears ARToolkit 5.3 uses FREAK but nothing prior to 5.2. However it is slow and inaccurate and does not use RANSAC for optimisation.